# For $1<k<n$, which of the following statement is true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n\ge 3$, $\{w_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$  be  a  basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$  such that the inner product $\{w_i,w_l\} =0$ whenever $j \neq l$. Let $W$ be  an arbitary subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and  $1 <  k < n$.

Which of the following statement is true?

a) There  exist $x \in W$ such that $x \neq 0$ and such that $(x,w_j) =0$ for all $1 \le j \le k-1$

b) If $\dim  W = k$, then there exist  $x \in W$ such that $x \neq 0$ and such that $(x,w_j) =0$ for all $1 \le j\le k-1$

c) If $\dim W > k$, then there exist  $x \in W $ such that $x \neq 0$ and such that $(x,w_j) =0$ for all $1 \le j \le  k-1$

I think here $k$ is less then $n$, $\ker W  \neq \{0\}$ so it is  linearly dependent, so all option a) ,b) and c) are obviously true.

Is my answer is correct? Any hints/solutions?

Comment: What does the first $<$ in "$< k < n$" possibly mean?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  i have edit its ..seee now

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{ker}W$ if $W$ is a subspace?